# 1 Button 4 Comboboxes On Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I have 1 button that will execute a stored procedure based off which combobox has data in it.  Are multiple `if` statements the best course for me to account for each combobox scenario?  I currently have my code like so - which works, but is a bit slow.  Is there a better way to write this syntax using C# and VS2013?

```
private void btn1_Click()
{
    if (cbo1.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo2.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo3.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo4.Text.ToString() == "" )
    {   
        MessageBox.Show("You failed to make a selection.");
        return;
    }
    if (cbo1.Text.ToString() != "" && cbo2.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo3.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo4.Text.ToString() == "" )  
    {
        //Go route1 
    }
    if (cbo1.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo2.Text.ToString() 1= "" && cbo3.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo4.Text.ToString() == "" )  
    {
      //Go route2 
    }
    if (cbo1.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo2.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo3.Text.ToString() != "" && cbo4.Text.ToString() == "" )  
    {
      //Go route3 
    }
    if (cbo1.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo2.Text.ToString() == "" &&  cbo3.Text.ToString() == "" && cbo4.Text.ToString() != "" ) 
    {
      //Go route4 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
@MethodMan --> is this how you would go about setting up the check?

```
var comboBoxes =  this.Controls
              .OfType<ComboBox>()
              .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox"));

foreach(var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
{
  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbBox.Text)) || if (cmbBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
  {
    //How to find which combobox is cmbBox
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this code is slow?

Comment: @LarsTech - when I execute it, it is sluggish.  That is why I ask if better way to write syntax.

Comment: you could do this a few ways to make it more readable I would use the .Controls class to check the control if it's a combobox and if the .Text property is not empty using the string.IsNullOrEmpty function..

Comment: It's not the code that's sluggish — probably the Stored Procedure has issues.  I'm guessing the user isn't allowed to pick an item in multiple comboboxes?

Comment: @LarsTech - Correct, only one combo box may have an item selected.

Comment: @MethodMan - see my edit, is that what you were saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion will be something like this:

```
private void btn1_Click()
{
int data = 0;
if(cbo1.Text.ToString() != "")
    data+=1;
if(cbo2.Text.ToString() != "")
    data+=2;
if(cbo3.Text.ToString() != "")
    data+=4;
if(cbo4.Text.ToString() != "")
    data+=8;
switch(data)
{
    case 1:
     //Go route1
    break;
    case 2:
     //Go route2
    break;
    case 4:
     //Go route3
    break;
    case 8:
     //Go route4
    break;
    default:
     MessageBox.Show("You failed to make a selection.");
    break;
}
}
```

i`m not sure it will do the job you want but it is a lot faster and this way you can check wich combo the user selected and wich combo he did not

Comment: What would you recommend to prevent a user from selecting a value from multiple comboboxes?  I only want to allow an input in one.  However, if the user by chance selected a value from two, two routes would take place.

Comment: the way i used binary data you can find out if user has selected muliple comboboxes or not.

Comment: there wont be two routes: for example he select cbo1 and cbo3 the data will be 5 witch is not in switch and will go to default case

Comment: Dehgham - I see that now.  My oversight.  Assigning the += value to data would sum the value so if multiple options are selected everything would be fine!